# Remove Focus Around Buttons on Click

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, button, lightning-button

I have a button named 'Apply Filters' and onclick of that button I am filtering data.I want to remove focus from the button once we are done clicking.
[image: Focused Button]

Once the button is click only on the click the focus should be there and after clicking the focus should be removed.

html code:

```
<button onclick={handleSeedFilter} 
        data-id="Seeds" 
        class="slds-button
        slds-button_neutral">
                       Apply Filters
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blur()` method removes keyboard focus from the current element.

Syntax:

> blur()

Parameters:

> None.

Return value:

> None (undefined).

**Examples**

Remove focus from a button

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="buttonId" onclick="focusAndBlurButton()">Click me to gain focus</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function focusAndBlurButton() {
  const buttonElement = document.getElementById("buttonId");

  buttonElement.focus();

  // The button will lose focus after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    buttonElement.blur();
  }, 3000);
}
```

So according to this, your code will be as below.

HTML:

```
<button onclick={handleSeedFilter} 
        data-id="Seeds" 
        class="slds-button
        slds-button_neutral">
                       Apply Filters
</button>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ButtonExample extends LightningElement {
    handleSeedFilter(event){
         this.template.querySelector('[data-id="Seeds"]').blur();
        // Rest of your code....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur method in handler, see the example

HTML

```
<button onclick={handleSeedFilter} 
        data-id="Seeds" 
        class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                       Apply Filters
</button>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ButtonBasic extends LightningElement {
    handleSeedFilter(event){
        this.template.querySelector('button.slds-button_neutral').blur();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove focus from the button after clicking it, you can use **JS to blur** the button element. Here's how you can achieve this:

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick={handleSeedFilter}
        data-id="Seeds"
        class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"
        ref={applyButton}>
    Apply Filters
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api dataId;
    @track showData = false;
    applyButton;

    // This function is called when the button is clicked
    handleSeedFilter() {
        // Your filtering logic goes here

        // After filtering, blur the button to remove focus
        this.applyButton.blur();
    }

    // This function is called after the component is rendered in the DOM
    renderedCallback() {
        // Get a reference to the button element using the 'ref' attribute
        if (this.applyButton) {
            return;
        }
        this.applyButton = this.template.querySelector('button[data-id="' + this.dataId + '"]');
    }
}
```

In this code, we use the ref attribute in the HTML to assign a reference to the button element. Then, in the JS, we use **this.applyButton.blur()** to blur the button element and remove the focus from it after the handleSeedFilter function is executed.

With this implementation, the focus will be on the button only while clicking it, and it will be removed immediately after clicking.

Hope this helps !